# splitting an array after an SQL query

Tags: php

could someone help me out?

I have done a straight forward MySQL query from a database to return all products.

I have used the productGroupDesc to tell me which company and category they belong to.  A typical entry looks like

Company - Category

So what im trying to do is categorise the products by first finding which company it belongs to and then the category.  Then simply list them.

Any ideas?

This is what i have so far:

```
global $__CMS_CONN__;
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM isproducts';
$arr = array();

$stmt = $__CMS_CONN__->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$listOfProducts = array();
while ( $row = $stmt->fetchObject() )
{ 
    $row->prodGroupDescList = explode(' - ',  $row->ProductGroupDescription);
    $listOfProducts[] = $row;
}
```

So from here i need help in creating the lists based on what they have in their productGroupDesc.

Comment: Thanks to alex i now have this code above which gives me the array but i just need to know how to group them by company and category and print them?

Comment: ProductGroupDescription should be another table, not silly dash separated field

Comment: Yes agreed but sometimes its unavoidable,  thanks for the input.

Comment: I don't think that the '$row->ProductGroupDescription' property will exist in your results objects since the SQL query you have in the snippet does not select that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `explode` method to split string into array.

Something like this.

```
$listOfProducts = array();
while ( $row = $stmt->fetchObject() )
{ 
    $row->prodGroupDescList = explode(' - ',  $row->ProductGroupDescription);
    $listOfProducts[] = $row;
}
```

Now to access the company and categories retrieve array elements:

```
$company = $row->prodGroupDescList[0]; // Will always be 1st element
$category = $row->prodGroupDescList[1]; // Will always be 2nd element
```

Comment: Thanks alex!  When i have the array then which is created in your example...how do i search for a company (there is only three) and print its categories?  Could you help me with that?  The categories are everything after the "-" when the match is made.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like what you wanted?

```
// Define this somewhere appropriate
function addToCategorisedList( $value, $category, array &$list )
{
    if ( !array_key_exists( $category, $list ) ) {
        $list[$category] = array();
    }
    $list[$category][] = $value;
}

// Then change the while loop to something like this
$categories = array();
$companies = array();

while ( $row = $stmt->fetchOject() )
{
    $row->prodGroupDescList = explode( ' - ',  $row->ProductGroupDescription );
    addToCategorisedList( $row, $$row->prodGroupDescList[0], $companies );
    addToCategorisedList( $row, $$row->prodGroupDescList[1], $categories );
}
```

I haven't tested this code so please let me know/correct it if there are any bugs in it.

Comment: This is useful but not quite what i was after.  Thanks though...
In the end i had something like

Comment: global $__CMS_CONN__;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM isproducts";

    $stmt = $__CMS_CONN__->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
 
 while ( $row = $stmt->fetchObject() )
 { 
  //echo $row->ProductGroupDescription.'<br />';
  $det = explode(' - ',  $row->ProductGroupDescription);
  if ( !in_array($det[1],$results_array[$det[0]]) ) $results_array[$det[0]][] = $det[1];
 }